# How do I display a tour on a node?

Tags: nodes, 9

On a Drupal 9 site, I installed the *Tour* and the *Tour UI* modules, and created a node.

How can I configure the *Tour UI* to show a tour on that node?

I don't know what to put in *Module name* and *Routes*.

> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help text shows you what to put in the "Routes" box:

```
entity.node.canonical
- node:3
```

The Tour UI helps you create a Tour, but that Tour will be saved as a YAML file in your own custom module. Or I guess you could also add a tour to an existing module. Either way, you need some place to put the tour code. Most sites have a custom module to hold site-specific customizations of Drupal. So yes, you should be able to use "node" here if you want.